# How to find a form element inside multiple frames using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, find, frames

I am working on a website that currently uses the old style frames. I want to go through a replace some javascript DOM calls because I am running into cross-browser issues. This is what I would like to replace.

```
window.parent.frames['topdisplay'].document.FORMSV2DISPLAY.action = 'what ever action';
```

In the above code my problem is that the 'document.FORMSV2DISPLAY' part doesn't work in IE I have to replace that part with document.form(0) and then of course neither of those work correctly in Chrome or Safari.

I would like to use jquery to find the form named FORMSV2DISPLAY and then perform my usual actions and submits.

I have tried things like

```
$(this).find('FORMSV2DISPLAY').action
$(parent).find('FORMSV2DISPLAY').action
$('topdisplay').find('FORMSV2DISPLAY').action
```

none of these return the same thing as the javascript DOM calls I am trying to replace. I am very new to jquery and help or understanding is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to set the action:

```
$('#topdisplay').find('#FORMSV2DISPLAY').attr('action', 'whateveraction');
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks. I think my problem was that missing # sign. Also thanks for the attr function.

Comment: Ok. I'm a little stuck maybe you can help me out again. I changed everything to use something like you said earlier.     $('#topdisplay').find('#FORMSV2DISPLAY').attr('action', 'whateveraction');

Comment: Sorry. Added comment before I was finished. But that doesn't work in IE I still have to use window.parent.frames['topdisplay'].document.forms[0].sAction.value = "Save";

Comment: I printed out the name of forms[0] and it is giving me the name that I am using in jquery for everything else. What in the world is going on? Why won't IE work with this and should I be doing something else?

Comment: No idea why. Can you assemble a jsFiddle scenario so that we could investigate? Also, what IE version is it?

Comment: Never used. jsFiddle at all. I'll ask some of my coworkers if they have.